# Sum of digits of 9(x+1) always equal to 9

Tags: modular-arithmetic

For $x=1,2,....,9$ we know $9(x+1)$ is a two digits number $A+B$.
Prove sum of digits($A+B$) always equal to 9.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $9(1)+1=10$, but $1+0\ne9$

Comment: Hint : Consider $10^n\equiv 1\mod 9$ for every positive integer $n$. This enables also the divisibility rule for $9$.

Comment: do we have to prove this only for a two digit number

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. It is 9(x+1)

Comment: Second hint : Use that the digit sum must be divisible by $9$. Then you only have to rule out digit sum $18$ or more and digit sum $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have $$9x=AB=10A+B$$
Then we have $$9(x+1)=10A+B=9A+(A+B)$$.

This gives us $$A+B=9(x+1)-9A=A+B=9(x+1-A). $$

Thus the sum of digits of $9(x+1)$ is $9(x+1-A)$. Since $9(x+1-A)$ is divisible by $9$, then so is the sum of digits of $9(x+1)$

Answer (score 0):

Just check all the cases if you are comfortable with that.

Otherwise:

If $n$ is a positive integer divisible by $9$ then show that the sum of digits of $n$ must be divisible by $9$.

Finally notice that since $9$ is the only non-zero one digit number which is a multiple of $9$, so if you continuously keep on summing the digits to eventually reach to a one digit number, then this number should be $9$, since at each step you will have a multiple of $9$ obtained by summing the digits.

This will tell you that if you start with any multiple of $9$ and keep summing the digits till you get a one digit number (after which you cannot proceed any further) then this must be $9.$

Comment: While this is true, the question isn't about taking successive sums. For example, the statement would be false for $x=10$.

Comment: I said x=1,...,9 not 10

Comment: Yes notice that if $x \in \{1 , .... , 9 \}$ then the sum of digits of $9(x+1)$ can never be more than $9$.

Comment: Yes, I asked for a solution to prove it.